# Object creation in modal operator

Tags: operator

I'm currently trying to create objects from random arrays, by using timer modal operator. However the code below doesn't work, and I think I miss some knowledge of Blender:

```
import bpy
import random
import time
from bpy_extras.object_utils import object_data_add

class ModalTimerOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "wm.modal_timer_operator"
    bl_label = "Modal Timer Operator"

    limits = bpy.props.IntProperty(default=0)
    _timer = None

    def add_object(self, context):
        verts = [(random.random()*10, random.random()*10, random.random()*10),(random.random()*10, random.random()*10, random.random()*10),(random.random()*10, random.random()*10, random.random()*10)]
        faces = [[0,1,2,3],[4,5,6,7],[0,4,7,3]]
        edges = []
        mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new(name='test')
        mesh.from_pydata(verts, edges, faces)
        object_data_add(context, mesh, operator=self)

    def modal(self, context, event):
        if event.type in {'RIGHTMOUSE', 'ESC'} or self.limits > 10:
            self.limits = 0
            self.cancel(context)
            return {'FINISHED'}

        if event.type == 'TIMER':
            XYZcoord = (random.random()*10, random.random()*10, random.random()*10)
            self.add_object(context)

            self.limits += 1

        return {'PASS_THROUGH'}

    def execute(self, context):
        wm = context.window_manager
        self._timer = wm.event_timer_add(time_step=0.5, window=context.window)
        wm.modal_handler_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def cancel(self, context):
        wm = context.window_manager
        wm.event_timer_remove(self._timer)


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ModalTimerOperator)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ModalTimerOperator)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
    bpy.ops.wm.modal_timer_operator()
```

The first iteration works fine, but then there's some issues with object_data_add. 
It throws out an error: 
`'ModalTimerOperator' object has no attribute 'layers'`

If I add definition of `self.layer`, then this error happens:
`TypeError: WM_OT_modal_timer_operator.is_property_set("location") not found`

Comment: I think you can remove the operator argument. Passing the operator is only for when you want to set location and rotation properties, which the operator would need to have, but yours doesn't.

Comment: You can check `2.79/scripts/modules/bpy_extras/object_utils.py` for the implementation of `object_data_add()`.

Comment: Thanks! that helped